# How to pass radio button values from two different activities to the third activity in android studio

Tags: java, android

I am trying make an get radio button values from first two activities and display/store in the database when submit button in third activity get clicked and sequence of activities is like Activity1->Activity2->Activity3. I have tried shared preference API,getExtra method and intent also ,but i don't know where i am doing wrong. Whenever i click on the submit button it says there is no data.

```
//In Activity1
 public void saveInfo(View view){
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("ques1",sa1.toString());
        editor.commit();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();






//In Activity3
//shared preferencess
    public void load(View view){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String q1 = sharedPreferences.getString("ques1",DEFAULT);

        Toast.makeText(ActivitySix.this, "q1 : " + sharedPreferences.getString("ques1",DEFAULT), 1000).show();


        if (q1.equals(DEFAULT))
            Toast.makeText(this, "No data found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(this, "Data loaded sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Comment: Can you please post the code which you currently have?

Comment: @RhysP , i put the code there now.

Comment: @ADM, As i know Intent is only pass the to the next activity. And my problem is pass the ActvityOne data to the ActivityThree and sequence of activity will be ActivityOne -> ActivityTwo -> ActivityThree. Do i need to store the values in ActivityTwo in some other variable??

Comment: Could you tell us exactly what "sa1" is please?

Comment: "sa1" it is storing the radio button value.

Answer (score -1):

In first activity check your data is saved or not? Have you applied editor.commit() while saving your data onSharedPreference

Comment: yes i applied editor.commit();

Comment: Check the gist https://gist.github.com/Fazalcs13/8883b08e858697596a64692b25163a76/revisions